# why is my class function not using my global variables?

Tags: c++

the string variable named 'listt'(intentional double "t") does not appear to be declared despite it existing as a global variable.

i looked online for a solution, and all i could find were people telling me to make sure i wasn't 'using namespace std;'...which a wasn't anyway.

```
  #include <iostream>
#include "sally.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//globals

/////////////r//c
//3 = what it is you're doing, the day its happening, the time its happening
string listt[7][3];

//functions
int main()
{
    int option1;
    while(option1 != -1){
   sally obj;

    option1 = obj.menuop();
    obj.direct(option1, obj);
    }
}
```

header file:

```
#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H


class sally
{

   public:
        sally();

        int menuop();
void direct(int a, sally obj);

void showlist();
void addlist();
void removelist();

        virtual ~sally();

    protected:

    private:

            int option1;
};

#endif // SALLY_H
```

body of the "addlist function"

```
void sally::addlist(){
    system("cls");
    string days[7] = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
    for(int num = 0; num<7; num++){
            listt[num][0] = days[num];
       cout<<"On "<<days[num]<<" you will ";
        cout<<...<<endl;
        cin>>listt[num][1];
        system("cls");
        cout<<"On "<<days[num]<<" you will "<<listt[num][1]<<" at *insert 24 hour time here*";
    cout<<"..."endl;
    cin>>listt[num][2];
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect you did not declare your `listt` global variable.  So `sally::addlist` doesn't know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.h` file you need to *declare* (not define) your global variable (outside the class).

```
extern string listt[7][3];
```

Every source file including this header file will see the *declaration*, but the *definition* only occurs in one module (the main source file here).